# log error to application insight from azure apim custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

i have one azure apim custom policy which intercepts the requests and does some pre-check.  If check fails in want to log it to appinsight before i return error response from this custom policy.

there is one policy log-to-event-hub but that i dont want to use if above is possible.

please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration with AppInsights is coming soon: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/16437151-application-insights-integration